# Flask application displaying list of items from SQL database as text

Tags: python, html, flask, web

I am trying to display a list of my items from the database in my flask application. Unfortunately, the list elements are placed into the HTML as text, instead of HTML code, what am I doing wrong and how to prevent this from happening?

My route function:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    try:
        products = Product.query.all()
        product_text = '<ul>'
        for product in products:
            product_text += '<li>' + product.title + ', ' + product.price + '</li>'
        product_text += '</ul>'
        return render_template('index.html', products=product_text)
    except Exception as e:
        error_text = "<p>The error:<br>" + str(e) + "</p>"
        hed = '<h1>Something is broken.</h1>'
        return hed + error_text
```

my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div class = item>
            {{ products }}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would better to pass products to template as a list:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    try:
        products = Product.query.all()
        return render_template('index.html', products=products)
    except Exception as e:
        error_text = "<p>The error:<br>" + str(e) + "</p>"
        hed = '<h1>Something is broken.</h1>'
        return hed + error_text
```

and then render template like that

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div class = item>
            <ul>
                {% for product in products %}
                    <li>{{product.title}}, {{product.price}}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that did help, and seems much more useful! This is my first flask project, good to learn useful stuff in the beggining of the journey ;D

Comment: @dovexz12323 you are welcome. This is a standard way to render tempaltes. Take a look on this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-templates-in-a-flask-application. Good luck on your learning path!